# Horizontal carousel gallery jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gallery

Could someone help me create a horizontal carousell gallery? The code isn't working properly, and it needs to be compatible with 31 images. It needs to formated in one line, and touch enabled, so it will scroll smoothly horizontally. It should appear as if it is a long strip of paper, which you can drag to one side or the other, freely. When onClick, is it possible to get the gallery fullscreen?

**Html**

```
 <ul id="scroller">
   <li><img src="image1.jpg" width="290" height="200"></li>
   <li><img src="image2.jpg" width="290" height="200"></li>
   <li><img src="image3.jpg" width="290" height="200"></li>
   ...
 </ul>
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.simplyscroll.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.simplyscroll.css" media="all" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
        $(function() { //on DOM ready 
            $("#scroller").simplyScroll();
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Container DIV - automatically generated */
.simply-scroll-container { 
    position: relative;
}

/* Clip DIV - automatically generated */
.simply-scroll-clip { 
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* UL/OL/DIV - the element that simplyScroll is inited on
Class name automatically added to element */
.simply-scroll-list { 
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.simply-scroll-list li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.simply-scroll-list li img {
    border: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Custom class modifications - adds to / overrides above

.simply-scroll is default base class */

/* Container DIV */
.simply-scroll { 
    width: 576px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

/* Clip DIV */
.simply-scroll .simply-scroll-clip {
    width: 576px;
    height: 200px;
}

/* Explicitly set height/width of each list item */ 
.simply-scroll .simply-scroll-list li {
    float: left; /* Horizontal scroll only */
    width: 290px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: I just can't get the code to work.. I have tried to change all off the code, but there is some errors. https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=7D7qoc3hSe

Comment: You have not described what is the error. Trust me no one is going to make things for you. We can just solve your errors.

Comment: And thats the problem.. i can't find the error. im not very good at these things, sorry..

Comment: If you look at the console, you'll see the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` and if you look in the javascript window, you'll see that you have `html` in there that doesnt belong, namely your `<script>` tags, you need to include those scripts as external resources in jsfiddle

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/qjbxvfg5/